# Tkinter Odd behaviour when inheriting from tk.Tk vs no inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've read many answers on SO that talk about how tkinter is not really Thread Safe even though it claims it is after I came across the infamous '**RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop**' error when attempting to use threading with my tkinter app. To better understand consider the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
# METHOD1: Inherit from tk.Tk
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = self
        self.root.title('InheritedRootWindow')
        self.strVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.num = 0
        self.strVar.set('MyButton')
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.__closeWindowCommand)
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.root, textvariable=self.strVar, command= self.__btnPressCommand ) #text='Button1'
        self.btn.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

# # METHOD2: No Inheritng
# class App():
#     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#         self.root = tk.Tk()
#         self.root.title('NoInheritanceRootWindow')
#         self.strVar = tk.StringVar()
#         self.num = 0
#         self.strVar.set('MyButton')
#         self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.__closeWindowCommand)
#         self.btn = tk.Button(self.root, textvariable=self.strVar, command= self.__btnPressCommand ) #text='Button1'
#         self.btn.pack()
#         self.root.mainloop()

    def __btnPressCommand(self):
        print('button pressed')
        self.num +=1
        self.strVar.set('MyButton%s'%self.num)
        # self.update()

    def __closeWindowCommand(self):
        print('Closing root window')
        self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=App).start()
    print('Done starting App thread')
```

1. When you run the code as is with Method1 (inheriting from tk.Tk, you will get the 'RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop' error message AFTER closing the window.
2. Then comment Method1 and run Method2, it will NOT give you the 'RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop' error upon closing the window.

Traceback from Method1:

```
Closing root window
Exception ignored in: <function Variable.__del__ at 0x000002A7D9FCB9D0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 363, in __del__
    if self._tk.getboolean(self._tk.call("info", "exists", self._name)):
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

**Question:**

WHY does it give the 'main thread is not in main loop' error upon closing window in Method1 and not in Method2 even though both are being run in a separate thread (not the main thread)?

Comment: @JRiggles - yea but that does not explain WHY Method2 works fine in a thread other than the main thread -- please read the explanation above